# How can I plot waveforms from hex data in python

Tags: python, serial-port, hex, ascii, pyserial

I would like to ask for helping me with this issue: I  have a device connected  to pc via RS232 and properly configured so I am getting data according to manufacturer. Data I get are in hex format and I would like to plot 5 waveforms from it. My data looks like this:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=4, bytesize=8, baudrate=115200, parity='N', stopbits=1)
x = ser.read(1000)
print(x) # x1c\x00\x00\xe0p\xf0\xe0\x00\xe0\x80\xfcp\x80\xfcpp\x00\x00\xe0\x00\xe0\x8e\xe0\x9e\x1c\x9e\xe0\xe0p\xf0\xe0\xfe\xfcp\xf0\xfcp\xfe\xfcp\x80\x1c\x00\xe0\x0e\xf0\xe0\x8e\xe0\x8e\x1c\x8e\xe0\xe0p\xf0\xe0\xfe\xfcp\xf0\xfcp\xfe\xfcp\x80\x1c\x00\xe0p\xf0\xe0\x8e\xe0\x8e\x1c\x8e\xe0\xe0p\xf0\xe0\xfe\xfcp\xf0\xfcp\xfe\xfcp\x80\x1c\x00\xe0~\xf0\xe0\x8e\xe0\x9e\x1c\x8e\xe0\xe0p\xf0\xe0\xfe\xfcp\xf0\xfcp\xfe\xfcp\x80\x1c\x00\xe0\x80\xfcp\x8e\xe0\x8e\x1c\x8e\xe0\xe0p\xf0\xe0\xfe\xfcp\xf0\xfcp\xfe\xfcp\x80\x1c\x00\xe0\x8e\xfcp\x8e\xe0\x8e\x1c\x8e\xe0\xe0p\xf0\xe0\xfe\xfc\xf0\xe0\xfcp\xfe\xfcp\x80\x1c\x00\xe0\xf0\xfcp\x8e\xe0\x8e\x1c\x8e\xe0\xe0p\xf0\xe0\xfe\xfcp\xf0\xfc\xf0\xfe\xfcp\x80\x1c\x00\xe0\xfe\xfcp\x8e\xe0\x8e\x1c\x8e\xe0\xe0\xf0\xf0\xe0\xfe\xfcp\xf0\xfcp\xfe\xf
```

I have some instruction from manufacturer and they are following:
device submits the data in a defined time interval. The time interval is 2 seconds.
The transmission of data is autonomic, means host do not have to send a ‚request‘.
Data is transmitted as data packets in a formatted string. A wave data package is transmitted every 400 milliseconds with samples of 5 waves.  The samples are of type “SHORT” and have the interval of 8 milliseconds, so the wave data frequency is 125 hz.:

Wave 1, Wave 2, Wave 3, Wave 4, Wave 5

The wave samples of 5 waves are transmitted as following:

Byte    Meaning

- 1 Start sequency ESC (hex. 0x1B)
- 2 CRC checksum Highbyte (same as in digital protocol)
- 3 CRC checksum Lowbyte (same as in digital protocol)
- 4 number of bytes of following data (Highbyte)
- 5 number of bytes of following data (Lowbyte)
- 6 Sample 1 Wave 1 Highbyte
- 7 Sample 1 Wave 1 Lowbyte
- 8 Sample 1 Wave 2 Highbyte
- 9 Sample 1 Wave 2 Lowbyte
- 10 Sample 1 Wave 3 Highbyte
- 11 Sample 1 Wave 3 Lowbyte
- 12 Sample 1 Wave 4 Highbyte
- 13 Sample 1 Wave 4 Lowbyte
- 14 Sample 1 Wave 5 Highbyte
- 15 Sample 1 Wave 5 Lowbyte
- 16 Sample 2 Wave 1 Highbyte
- 17 Sample 2 Wave 1 Lowbyte
- 18 Sample 2 Wave 2 Highbyte
- 19 Sample 2 Wave 2 Lowbyte
- 20 Sample 2 Wave 3 Highbyte
- 21 Sample 2 Wave 3 Lowbyte
- 22 Sample 2 Wave 4 Highbyte
- 23 Sample 2 Wave 4 Lowbyte
- 24 Sample 2 Wave 5 Highbyte
- 25 Sample 2 Wave 5 Lowbyte
- 26...

On device curves looks like this:
[Sample graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8hbC.png)

Thanks for any advice

Comment: If you have documented material, it's better to provide a reference link to it, rather than explaining it in prose in your question. In addition, it would be nice to have vendor/model/configuration information for that device.

Comment: Understood, but this is all I got from manufacturer. It is rarely used medical so vendor /model wont help much. In this case I need a hint how to encode and sort incoming data.

Comment: It seems that there is no 0x1B in the printed data and there are some 0x1C. Is the specified specification or the received data wrong?

Comment: No I couldn't found 0x1B either. Even though I received 1000 bytes of data there was no 0x1B.  Maybe I can double check my serial setting.